# Best practice when constructing if statement based on datatype?

Tags: python, if-statement, types

I am constructing a basic function with an if statement based on datatype. I am wondering whether there is any problem with using:

```
if type(number) == int:
```

in something like:

```
def distance_from_zero(number):
"""Takes input 'number', checks datatype. If integer or floating point, returns absolute value. If other, returns 'Nope'"""
if type(number) == int:
    return abs(number)
elif type(number) == float:
    return abs(number)
else:
    return "Nope"
```

distance_from_zero(45)

Is there a cleaner/better way to use datatypes in if statements?

Comment: In the spirit of duck typing, it is considered bad form to check types explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why even check?

```
try:
    return abs(number)
except TypeError:
    return 'Nope'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use isinstance()

```
if isinstance(number, (int, float)):
    return abs(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with that code, although you can write it more simply as:

```
if type(number) in (int, float):
    return abs(number)
else:
    return "Nope"
```